# Get the parent of the parent of my pid (aka getpppid())

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way to get the parent of the parent of my pid? There is `getpid()` and `getppid()`, I'm looking for the "`getpppid()`"

PS: I'm on Linux, and the code will be run only on Linux (Not Unix nor any other variants)

Comment: I've had the same problem a while ago - I don't think there's a function that produces the value, but you can traverse `/proc/<pid>/status` and read ppids from there. However, if you're forking yourself, you can just store your own pid early enough.

Comment: bear in mind it's a lot easier to read `/proc/<pid>/stat` - see [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for the details of what each column reads, and how to `scanf` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are.

```
pid_t getpppid(void)
{
    char exe[256],proc[81],state;
    FILE *fp;
    int pid,ppid=-1;

    snprintf(proc,81,"/proc/%d/stat",(int)getppid());
    fp=fopen(proc,"r");
    if(fp)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d %s %c %d",&pid,exe,&state,&ppid);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return (pid_t)ppid;
}
```

**EDIT:** Just remeber that if your parent or your process called setuid() since start, your program may not have privileges to read that process stat.

Comment: I was just looking at that exact same code, found in linuxforums :)